# Android: how to open menu where user clicks

Tags: android, listview, android-menu

Is it possible to open a menu in the exact point where the user has clicked?

I have a custom listview and I'd like to show a menu like the right click on Windows in the point where the user clicks on the listview item.

Comment: Check this tutorial http://keepsafe.github.io/2014/11/19/building-a-custom-overflow-menu.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. Take a look at [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html), which lets you do exactly that. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
listItemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Create an instance of the PopupMenu
        PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, listItemView);
        // Inflate the menu using a menu layout file
        menu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

        menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // Do something here if correct MenuItem selected
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done this, and it works great, the only problem is that it opens the popup under or over the item clicked, is there any way to open it exactly at the x and y where the user clicks?

Comment: The docs say "The popup will appear below the anchor view if there is room, or above it if there is not", so it doesn't look like that's possible out-of-the-box due to how Android measures it's views.

Comment: Actually it looks like it's possible [from API19 onwards](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html#PopupMenu(android.content.Context,%20android.view.View,%20int)). Use `new PopupMenu(this, v, Gravity.CENTER);` and see if that's more like what you wanted.